# How to hide directory name from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my site url structure as follows: http://www.sitename.com/new/about-us .

What I really want to do now is hide the directory name 'new' from the above url, but the admin url should remain unchanged.

The admin url would be like : http://www.sitename.com/new/admin .

My previous .htaccess code as follows:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /new/

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/new/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule blog/ - [L]
  RewriteRule (^wlp) - [L]

  RewriteRule admin/ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([\S\s/+.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is my server directory structure:

```
  /public
    /new
      .htaccess
      index.php
      about-us.php
      /blog
      /admin
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is a [common technique](https://github.com/phalcon/php-site/blob/master/.htaccess) which I've seen before for forwarding all *public_html* requests to *public_html/public* to essentially hide the contents of the *public_html* directory from the user and making *public_html/public* the new web root.

Try using this in your `public_html/.htaccess` file (you can write further htaccess in *public_html/new/.htaccess*):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#enforce www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#forward all requests, except new/admin, to the 'new' directory without the user's awareness
RewriteRule  new/admin  -  [S=2]
RewriteRule  ^$ new/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I looked and that is the directory structure I was expecting however you are using `public` instead of `public_html`. So when I say `public_html/.htaccess` that means `public/.htaccess`. Meaning to put my .htaccess into your web root: `/`. Regarding your old htaccess file sitting in `/new/.htaccess`, it requires no edits.

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation. I have followed your response and put the newly created .htaccess file (with your above code) under public directory. My previous .htaccess file which is under 'new' directory retain unchanged.

Currently the homepage works fine. But when I click on 'about-us' page it doesn't work.

Here is my site url :  http://www.spadvertising.com.

Comment: You may have to adjust the code in your index.php accordingly to match the `$_GET['url']` being passed in. What happens if at the top of your index.php you do: `echo $_GET['url'];exit;` before anything else has a chance to run and you visit http://www.spadvertising.com/about-us? does it get rewritten to `new/about-us` properly or does it remain `about-us`?

Comment: I see your test and it isn't including the `/new/` as I was expecting. I believe all you need to do now is edit your `/new/.htaccess` file's rewrite to add it in for the $_GET['url'] like so:
`RewriteRule ^([\S\s/+.]+)/?$ index.php?url=new/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess in / should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: there may be an another reason for that.